# What is the siglum for the Arabic Diatessaron?

Tags: textual-criticism

I have browsed the Internet quite a bit but could not find the scribal abbreviation for the Diatessaron (maybe an established siglum for it does not exist).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. According to Wikipedia, the original text of Tatian’s Syrian Diatessaron (circa second century) has not survived and was reconstructed in 1881 by Theodor Zahn from translations and commentaries.

Comment: @Lesley: thanks for your comment. One cannot rely on Wikipedia. I was referring to the Arabic forgeries from 1107 CE, allegedly translated from the Syriac (which is arguable). The tale that heretical Tatian wrote a Diatessaron was Rome's smokescreen for confiscating and destroying the Gospel according to the Hebrews in the mid-fourth century. Anyway, I am only interested in the siglum for the Arabic forgery.

Comment: Sorry... - the text was seized in the mid-fifth century.